# Dynamic in DatagridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

If value in row = "No payment" I need show ComboBox in data template, else I dont show combobox in row, how can I do this?

Here is my datagridtemplate:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Time">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding date_payment, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayConverter}}" Width="135" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox IsReadOnly="False" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged_1" Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyle}" Height="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="135">
                <ComboBox.BorderBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource Color1}"/>
                </ComboBox.BorderBrush>
                <ComboBox.Items>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Payment</ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox.Items>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I think the need to use event `LoadinRow`, but I can not think of, if I set `Name` my combobox then isn't visible (in code)?

Please help! Thank you :)

---

### **Answer:**

```
<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding date_payment, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayConverter}}" Value="Не оплачено">
  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
 </DataTrigger>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to register to an Event. Simply create a `DataTrigger` within your `ComboBox` declaration.

```
 <ComboBox>
         <ComboBox.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding [Name of your property]}" Value="No payment">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </ComboBox.Triggers>
      </ComboBox>
```

Another (maybe better) approach would be to implement a Property on the Object you bind to with a boolean indicating the current state of the customer (e. g. NoPayment etc.).
You then could bind to this value to the ComboBoxes `Visibility` Property using a Converter which translates this state to a target `Visibility` value.